# TKinter/matplotlib graphs won't update/run

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, graph, arduino

Im trying to display the data i get from the serial port(which is sent from an arduino) on to a graph. I've tried a ton of different stuff but it doesn't seem to be working as intended. I'm trying to have the x axis as the time since the program started and the y axis as the data i get from the serial port which is sent from the arduino. I've tried debugging but no errors come up.  the code seems to stop somewhere in the update_graphs() function but i can't tell what's causing it to stop. i'm so lost and dont know what to try now

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import serial
import threading
import queue
import time

# Function to read data from the serial port
def read_serial_data(serial_port, data_queue):
    while True:
        try:
            line = serial_port.readline().decode().strip()
            data_queue.put(line)
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            pass

# Function to update the graphs
def update_graphs():
    start_time = time.time()
    global x_data
    while True:
        try:
            data = data_queue.get_nowait()

            # Calculate the time since the program started
            current_time = time.time() - start_time

            # Update the graphs with the new data and time
            x_data.append(current_time)

            # Attempt to add data to y_data as a float
            try:
                y_data.append(float(data))
            except ValueError:
                print(f"Error converting data to float: {data}")
                
            x_data = x_data[-len(y_data):] #limits data in the list

            ax1.clear()
            ax1.plot(x_data, y_data, label='Sensor Data 1')
            ax1.set_xlabel('Time (seconds)')
            ax1.set_ylabel('Sensor Data 1')
            ax1.legend()

            canvas.draw()

        except queue.Empty:
            pass
        root.after(100, update_graphs)

# GUI setup
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Sensor Data Graphs")

# Serial port setup
ser = serial.Serial("COM5", baudrate=9600)

# Data queue for inter-thread communication
data_queue = queue.Queue()

# Create and start a thread to read data from the serial port
serial_thread = threading.Thread(target=read_serial_data, args=(ser, data_queue), daemon=True)
serial_thread.start()

# Create and start a thread to update the graphs
update_thread = threading.Thread(target=update_graphs, daemon=True)
update_thread.start()

# Create multiple graphs
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
x_data, y_data = [], []  # Lists to store data and corresponding time

# Create Tkinter canvas for embedding Matplotlib figure
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas_widget = canvas.get_tk_widget()
canvas_widget.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

# Start the Tkinter main loop
root.mainloop()
```

Arduino code

```
void setup() {
  
    Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(random(0, 50));
  delay(200);
}
```

I've tried slowing the Arduino code down thinking that the it was sending data too fast for the python script to read  but it didn't work

*UPDATE*

**Pretty certain that it's something to do with timing cause when i used debugging in vscode and went line by line everything worked but then when i let it run by itself, it just froze and wouldn't do anything**.

Arduino code stayed the same

updated code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import serial
import threading
import queue
import time

# Function to read data from the serial port
def read_serial_data(serial_port, data_queue):
    while True:
        try:
            line = serial_port.readline().decode().strip()
            data_queue.put(line)
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            pass

# Function to update the graphs
def update_graphs(start_time):
    while True:
        try:
            data = data_queue.get(timeout=1)

            # Calculate the time since the program started
            current_time = time.time() - start_time

            # Update the graphs with the new data and time
            x_data.append(current_time)
            y_data.append(float(data))

            ax1.clear()
            ax1.plot(x_data, y_data, label='Sensor Data 1')
            ax1.set_xlabel('Time (seconds)')
            ax1.set_ylabel('Sensor Data 1')
            ax1.legend()

            canvas.draw()

        except queue.Empty:
            pass
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in update_graphs: {e}")

# GUI setup
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Sensor Data Graphs")

# Serial port setup
ser = serial.Serial("COM5", baudrate=9600)

# Data queue for inter-thread communication
data_queue = queue.Queue()

# Create and start a thread to read data from the serial port
serial_thread = threading.Thread(target=read_serial_data, args=(ser, data_queue), daemon=True)
serial_thread.start()

# Create multiple graphs
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
x_data, y_data = [], []  # Lists to store data and corresponding time

# Create Tkinter canvas for embedding Matplotlib figure
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas_widget = canvas.get_tk_widget()
canvas_widget.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

# Get the start time
start_time = time.time()

# Schedule the update_graphs function to run every 100 milliseconds
root.after(200, update_graphs, start_time)

# Start the Tkinter main loop
root.mainloop()
```

*UPDATE*

**the graph seems to only update when i pause and unpause the program using the debugging feature in vscode**

Comment: There is no point in putting `update_graphs` in its own thread. Try looking at the documentation and examples of how `.after` works. Right now your problem is how `update_graphs` tries to loop.

Comment: Should i keep keep the serial port reading function in a thread or should i just change everything to the update_graphs()? e.g read the serial port and update the graph in the same function?

Answer (score 0):

One can use `matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation` to update a matplotlib figure when data changes. This answer provides a demo based on this approach (based around the idea of the question).

---

##### End Result

The following `gif` shows an output of the demo program.

[image: A dynamically updating matplotlib plot inside a tkinter window in Python3.]

##### Code

```
import threading, time, random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import queue
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

# Initialising objects to handle data
dataQueue = queue.Queue()
sensor_data = []
time_data = []

# This function mimics data generated from an arduino for this demo program
# Replace this with actual arduino-data-reading function
# This function is generating some random data every 0.2 seconds
def arduino():
    while(True):
        dataQueue.put(random.randint(1,10))
        time.sleep(0.2)

# Initialising the arduino function in separate thread, so, it generates data
# independently and in parallel to our plotting logic
arduinoThread = threading.Thread(target = arduino, daemon= True)
arduinoThread.start()

# Initialising the matplotlib figure and axis objects
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# This function reads data from data-queue, adds time-data and updates the 
# graphs according to the new data. If there is no data, exception occurs
# and the function skips the update.
def updateGraph(frame_number):
    try:
        sensor_data.append(dataQueue.get(timeout=1))
        time_data.append(time.time())
        ax.clear()
        ax.plot(time_data, sensor_data, color = 'orange')
        ax.set_ylabel('Sensor Data')
        ax.set_xlabel('Time')
    except queue.Empty:
        pass

# Creating the tkinter root window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Sensor Data')

# Setting a text label (optional) in tkinter window
tk.Label(master = root, text = 'Sensor 1 Data', font = ('Courier', 15, 'bold')).pack(side = 'top', pady = 10)

# Create Tkinter canvas for embedding Matplotlib figure
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas_widget = canvas.get_tk_widget()
canvas_widget.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

# Initialising the matplotlib FuncAnimation which calls the updateGraph function every 500 milli-second
anim = FuncAnimation(fig, updateGraph, interval = 500)  # interval between each update (or frame) in milli-seconds

# Launching the tkinter window
root.mainloop()
```

##### Explanation

I have put most of the assistive information required to understand the code in comments inside the code. Basically, we have created a `matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation` object for the matplotlib figure i.e. `fig` which calls the `updateGraph` function periodically after time specified in the `interval` parameter.

The `updateGraph` tries to read data from the `dataQueue`. If it finds data, it reads one data value from the `dataQueue` and adds it to the `sensor_data` followed by adding current time to `time_data` and finally update the figure (`fig`). If the `dataQueue` is empty, exception occurs and it skips updating data and graph for the iteration.

*Note: Since we don't have an Arduino for this demo, I created a function named `arduino` which generates some random data every 0.2 seconds and runs in parallel to the plotting program via `arduinoThread` to mimic the behavior of sensor data generated by a real Arduino.*